# Use Jquery with wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

How to use jQuery with Wordpress plugin?

My code:

```
require_once("view.php");
add_filter('the_content', 'test');
add_action('wp_head', 'ss_load_script');
add_action('wp_footer','display_copyright');


function ss_load_script(){
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery_new', get_bloginfo('url')."/wp-content/plugins/Test/jquery_new.js", array(), '', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress already loads jquery: if you are trying to load a DIFFERENT version of jQuery you might end up having conflict issues between the standard version and your version.

If you need jQuery just use the default jQuery library that Wordpress loads. Otherwise you will either overwrite the existing jQuery library (which could probably work out fine for you: your code above would work) or you have to do some javascript magic to copy the existing jquery to another object before you load your new copy and then restore it after you're done.

Comment: Can give me a small example (coding)? i am first time with wordpress.

Comment: Use this: `add_action( 'init', 'ss_init' ); function ss_init(){ wp_enqueue_script('njquery', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'jquery.js', array(), false, true); }` and this should load a custom jquery file that is in your plugin directory. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script for more detail

Comment: if want to display javascript alert in wordpress plugin what can i do ? Can give a small simple coding for me ? thank very much